# what's the difference of echoing the variables in this way?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

What is the difference of echoing these variable in bash scripting?

EXAMPLE:

I declare a variable

```
VARIABLE="Hello World"

echo $VARIABLE
```

What's the difference between the one above and this below?

```
echo ${VARIABLE}
```

Does it make a difference if I put {} or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No difference in your code

The curly braces, To delimiting a variable name are used for [parameter expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC31) so you can do things like

Truncate a variable' content

```
$ var="abcde"; echo ${var%e*}
abcd
```

Make substitutions similar to sed

```
$ var="abcde"; echo ${var/e/1}
abcd1
```

Braces can also be useful when the expansion occurs in certain contexts.  For example:

```
FOO=bar
echo $FOO1    # tries to print the value of a variable named "FOO1"
echo ${FOO}1  # prints "bar1"
```